# Julia Plots.jl Latex issue

Tags: plot, julia

Plotting in Julia has been a pain for me thus far. I do

```
using Plots.jl
```

Initially the plotting was fine, even with latex expressions. However, something must have changed (I don't know what), and now when I wish to plot something with latex expression in the axis or title, for example:

```
plot(
    p1,p2,
    layout=layout,
    link=:y,#aligns y-axis gridlines
    size = (800, 400),
    xtickfontsize=15,ytickfontsize=15, 
    xlab="s " *L" [h^{-1}Mpc]", 
    ylab=L"|x_s^2\xi_l^{bisector ,(2)}(s)/\xi_l^{pp}(s)|")
```

I get the error message:

```
latex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
latex: failed to create a dvi file
```

Furthermore, my plots are not longer being shown in Jupyter notebook (although I save them, and when I look at what was saved, the plots are there, although with messed up Latex).

Is there any easy fix for this?

I have tried using PyPlots (and PyCall to call it from python) but seem to have an issue importing that. For now I would prefer to stick with pure Julia plotting libraries, and be able to use them with latex.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your TeX installation, does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530420/how-to-get-rid-of-pdflatex-major-issue-so-far-no-miktex-administrator-has-che) help?

Comment: Yes this does not look like a Plots.jl issue